# States’ Power Over Other States

Tags: united-states, us-state-laws, federalism

Simple question:  Can a state enforce its laws against another state.  For example, say Tennessee outlaws gasoline powered cars.  A Georgia official intends to drive a state-owned gasoline powered vehicle to Kentucky on official business.  Can Tennessee force them to go the long way around, or does Georgia have sovereign immunity from Tennessee law?

Comment: This question belongs in legal, not politics.

Comment: Driving on official state business doesn't allow you to violate traffic laws on speeding, drink driving, vehicle safety, etc. Subnational entities don't have sovereign immunity. But yes this is a legal question.

Comment: OTOH: in which circumstances a state SHOULD be able to enforce laws against officials from another state would be on topic. (and an interesting Q as well)

Comment: A state enforcing the law within its own borders isn't enforcing it on other states. Everyone has to follow the laws of the state while in it even officials from other states.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it should be on history stackexchange

Comment: I'd argue Law, not History. While Dredd Scott et al are historical, it's also not entirely final. Either way, it is not a question about politics.

Comment: I will migrate it to law stack exchange then.